# Flutter - how to trigger a RaisedButton Programmatically?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a RaisedButton.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("MyHomePageState build");
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("test")),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("Page2");
            },
            child: Text("jump"),
          )
        ],
      )
    );
  }
```

How can I trigger this button's onTap() method by code programmatically rather than click this button?

Comment: do you want it to be triggered as the user enters the route? or you want it to be triggered on some event?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just create a separate function and call this method programmatically:

```
void triggerButton() {
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("Page2");
}
```

Then, call it like so:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("MyHomePageState build");
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("test")),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              triggerButton();
            },
            child: Text("jump"),
          )
        ],
      )
    );
  }
```

Comment: using your method, can not simulator the button press effect

Comment: It's more complicated to simulate the press effect, you'll need to create a custom widget [like this](https://gist.github.com/loushou/2b3c4e46a7931b40fc15a15069a03cec)

Answer (score -1):

Simply copy that `onPressed()` functions body and wrap it in a function as:

```
void onTapRaised(){
  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("Page2");
}

RaisedButton(
  onPressed:onTapRaised,
  child:Text("Jump"),
)
```

now you can call `onTapRaised` programmatically from anywhere in the same page.

Comment: using your method, can not simulator the button press effect